# Button action with Combine framework

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

What is the best approach to implement reactive programming for a button action event?

Regarding the guides and samples, I found only examples with **SwiftUI** `@State`.

I mean something like this:

```
@State var isVisible = false

....

Button(action: {
    self.isVisible.toggle()
} 

....

if isVisible {
    Text("texty text")
}
```

But what if I want to execute a background task?
The obvious approach is just call `viewModel?.pleaseDoAction()` inside `Button.action(`, and create a custom Subject which is triggered inside `pleaseDoAction()`:

```
final class ViewModel {
    func pleaseDoAction() {
        mySubject.send("some")
    }
}
```

But is this a correct architecture approach for **SwiftUI + Combine**?
In brief, button action should be a Publisher but this doesn't.

Comment: It is the right approach - when you think about it Buttons, TextFields, Pickers are all publishers - they notify interested parties of any changes to their values using Bindings.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa s, what's an example?

Answer (score 6):

The ViewModel approach by @Partha G is probably most appropriate, but here is a simple approach that doesn't require a view model.

As forewarning, this approach may not mesh well with SwiftUI view refreshing, if your view does that.  But for this very simple case, it appears to work well.

1. Add a PassthroughSubject to your view, as follows:

```
// Your view with a button:

import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct MyAwesomeView: View {
    
    public var buttonPressedSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Push This Button", action: {
            self.buttonPressedSubject.send()
        })
    }
}
```

2. Subscribe to and use that subject like this:

```
import Combine

class A {
    
    private var cancelBag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    private let myView: MyAwesomeView
    
    init(view: MyAwesomeView) {
        self.myView = view
        
        myView.buttonPressedSubject
            .sink { (_) in
                print("The button was pressed.")
        }
        .store(in: &cancelBag)
        
    }
}
```

3. Example usage in a playground:

```
// <#Copy-paste code from above here#>
import PlaygroundSupport

let playgroundView = MyAwesomeView()
let playgroundExample = A(view: playgroundView)
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(playgroundView)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

1. Using `@Published`

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var isVisible = false 
}

struct SampleView: View {
  @ObservedObject var model = ViewModel()

  Button(action: {
     self.model.isVisible.toggle()
  }) {
     Text("...")
  }
}
```

2. Leveraging the publisher of `Combine`

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   let objChanges = ObservableObjectPublisher() 

   var isVisible: Bool = false {
      willSet {
          objChanges.send()
      }
   }
}
```

`View` for the second would be very similar to the first.

Also, the lessons from [Paul Hudson](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/100/swiftui) and WWDC2019 might provide additional insight into the above wrappers and their usage.

Comment: So, we use a publisher

Comment: Refer to this video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226